# How to respond to Einstein Bot after-hours message during business hours?

Tags: businesshours, facebook, bots, einstein-chatbot

**Background**

A Facebook Messenger Einstein Bot has an business-hours check as the first action, if it is out of business-hours it sends a message informing them that no one is available.

**Question**

How can the customer support agents respond to the Facebook Messenger user once the office opens back up in the morning?

Currently, there isn't a message available for the agent to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user whether they want an agent to get back to them. Their positive answer would be the message you are looking for.